# How to show that topological groups are automatically Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, separation-axioms

On page 146, James Munkres' textbook Topology(2ed),

> Show that $G$ (a topological group) is Hausdorff. In fact, show that if $x \neq y$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $e$ such that $V \cdot x$ and $V \cdot y$ are disjoint.

Noticeably, the definition of topological group in Munkres's textbook differs from that in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group).

> A **topological group** $G$ is a group that is also a topological space **satisfying the $T_1$ axiom**, such that the map of $G \times G$ into $G$ sending $x \times y$ into $x \cdot y$ and the map of $G$ into $G$ sending $x$ into $x^{-1}$, are continuous maps.

Comment: Just to clarify, some people use a definition of a topological group which does not include $T_1$, so those won't be Hausdorff.

Comment: What is $T_1$ for Munkres?

Comment: @Sigur That points are closed.

Comment: @Sigur: All definitions of $T_1$ that I’ve seen are equivalent, so it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I know that. I've just asked to suggest him to read about $T_1$ spaces.

Comment: **Hint:** $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed. Use the fact that $e$ is closed and work with some good continuous function related with the diagonal.

Comment: For Further Reading;

If $G$ is a topologial group the following conditions are equivalent. 

i) $G$ is a  $T_{0}$ space.

ii) $G$ is a $T_{1}$ space.

iii) $G$ is a $T_{2}$ space.

iv) If $\beta_{e} $ is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of $e$ then $\cap \beta_{e} =\{e\}  $.

v) \{e\} is a closed subgroup of $G$.

vi) For all $f:H\rightarrow G$ in $\tau g$, $Kerf$ is a closed subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A space $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta_X\subseteq X\times X$ is closed. Consider the map $G\times G\rightarrow G$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto xy^{-1}$. It is continuous by the axioms for a topological group, and the diagonal is the inverse image of the the identity $\{e\}$, which is closed by assumption. So $G$ is Hausdorff if $\{e\}$ is closed, i.e., if $G$ is $T_1$ (by homogeneity, $T_1$ for $G$ is equivalent to $\{e\}$ being closed).

Given $x\neq y$ in a Hausdorff $G$, let $U_x$ and $U_y$ be disjoint opens around $x$ and $y$, respectively. Both $U_xx^{-1}$ and $U_yy^{-1}$ are opens around $e$, so we can find open $V$ with $e\in V\subseteq U_xx^{-1}\cap U_yy^{-1}$. Then $Vx$ and $Vy$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$, as desired.

Comment: Why are Vx and Vy closed?

Comment: My argument does not assert that they are closed. They are *open*. They may or may not be closed, but this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

A topological space $G$ is hausdorff iff the diagonal in $G\times G$ is closed. Can you see how the diagonal is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map?

Answer (score 5):

By the above argument, there are two cases:

1. If $\{1\}$ is closed then the diagonal is closed (as it is the inverse image of $\{1\}$ under the continuous map $g_1 \times g_2\mapsto g_1g_2^{-1}$). So $G$ is Hausdorff.
2. If $\{1\}$ is open then $G$ is discrete, so it's Hausdorff.