# Locally Euclidean Space implies T1 space

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that every locally Euclidean space is actually a $T_1$ space but I do even know how to start. Any help that you bring to me will be appreciated...

Comment: What would happen if there were two distinct points that could not be separated by any open sets? Remember, we can always find a neighborhood around any point that is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @JohnDouma a locally Euclidean space need not be Hausdorff.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If we took an open neighborhood $U$ around $x$ that was homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ and also contained $y$, couldn't we then get two open subsets of $U$ that separated $x$ and $y$, yielding a contradiction?

Comment: @JohnDouma no, look up the line with two origins, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, thank you. That's because the basis elements that contain each origin also contain intervals which will always intersect. Thus, even though $O_1\not\in (-a,0)\cup \{O_2\}\cup (0,a)$ the two basis elements always intersect.

Comment: @JohnDouma Hausdorff is not a "local enough" property, and $T_1$ is. It's a nice example (a standard one in topological manifold theory).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \neq y$ in $X$. Let $U$ be an open Euclidean neighbourhood of $x$. If $y \notin U$ we are done. If not, in the Euclidean (hence $T$-whatever) subspace $U$ we can find an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that misses $y$.
As $V$ is still open in $X$ ("open in open is open"), the same $V$ witnesses $T_1$-ness for $x,y$.

In short, a locally $T_1$ (or $T_0$) space is globally $T_1$ (resp. $T_0$).

The same argument shows that a locally $R_0$ space is globally $R_0$, where an [$R_0$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) is one where, for any two topologically distinguishable points, each has a neighbourhood not containing the other point.